# Lua string.format options

Tags: string, lua, string-formatting

This may seem like a stupid question, but what are the symbols used for string replacement in string.format? can someone point me to a simple example of how to use it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

string.format in Lua follows the same patterns as Printf in c:

https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

There are some exceptions, for those see here:

http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/string.format

Answer (score 10):

[Chapter 20 of PiL](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.html) describes `string.format` near the end:

> The function `string.format` is a
>   powerful tool when formatting strings,
>   typically for output. It returns a
>   formatted version of its variable
>   number of arguments following the
>   description given by its first
>   argument, the so-called format string.
>   The format string has rules similar to
>   those of the `printf` function of
>   standard C: It is composed of regular
>   text and directives, which control
>   where and how each argument must be
>   placed in the formatted string.

The [Lua Reference](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.format) says:

> The format string follows the same
>   rules as the `printf` family of standard
>   C functions. The only differences are
>   that the options/modifiers `*`, `l`, `L`, `n`,
>   `p`, and `h` are not supported and that
>   there is an extra option, `q`.

The function is implemented by [`str_format()` in `strlib.c`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lstrlib.c.html#str_format) which itself interprets the format string, but defers to the C library's implementation of `sprintf()` to actually format each field after determining what type of value is expected (string or number, essentially) to correspond to each field.

Answer (score 6):

There should be "Lua Quick Reference" html file in your hard disk, if you used an installation package.
(for example: ../Lua/5.1/docs/luarefv51.html)

There you'll find, among other things,

`string.format (s [, args ])`

- Formatting directives
- Formatting field types
- Formatting flags
- Formatting examples

Answer (score 4):

To add to the other answers: Lua does have a boolean data type, where C does not. C uses numbers for that, where 0 is `false` and everything else is `true`.

However, to format a boolean in a String in Lua,

```lua
local text = string.format("bool is %d", truth)
```

gets (at least in Hammerspoon):

> bad argument #2 to 'format' (number expected, got boolean)

You can instead use `%s` for booleans (as for strings):

```
local text = string.format("bool is %s", truth)
```