# Lua number currency format

Tags: sdk, formatting, lua, numbers, coronasdk

In lua, how can I format a number to have 2 decimal places?
I have a value example: 25.333 and I want it to display 25.33 instead.
Sometimes it's an integer like 55 and I want it to display 55.00 instead. This is for displaying currency values. I've tried example formatting functions, and none do what I want.
Any advice is appreciated.
Jerry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811884/lua-string-format-options). Basically, you'd want something like:

```
rdahlgren@deimos: pts/1: 5 files 48Kb$ lua
Lua 5.2.0  Copyright (C) 1994-2011 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> x = 25
> y = 25.3333
> print(string.format("%.2f", x))
25.00
> print(string.format("%.2f", y))
25.33
>
```

Comment: How about locale differences? Is it possible to have a comma as decimal separator?