# Why is 0.575 * 100 not same as 57.5?

Tags: lua

Why is 57.5 not same as 57.5? For example:

```
> b = 57.5
> print (57.5 == b)
true

> c = 0.575 * 100    
> print (c)
57.5

> print (c == b)
false

> print (c, b)
57.5    57.5
```

So somehow even though both c and b is 57.5, the numbers are not equal

Is there perhaps a rounding issue? but shouldn't the numbers print differently if that's so?

Edit:
Excellent, is there a way to print the actual value in LUA? Like if I want it to print 57.4999999999...?

Comment: [_What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating Point_](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
b=57.499999999999996
c = 0.575 * 100   
print (c==b)
```

This will return True.
Actually, If you enter .575

```
"%.17f" % 0.575
```

it returns 0.57499999999999996.

Answer (score 3):

It's the same reason `(1/3) * 3` won't give you the same result as `1` in fixed-precision decimal arithmetic. There is no representation that can be multiplied by `3` to give `1` in fixed-precision decimal.

They print the same because the printing code rounds the output. Would you want `(1/3) * 3` to print as `.999999999999999` or `1`?

Try this:

```
b = 57.5
c = 0.575 * 100
print (string.format("b = %.24f", b))
print (string.format("c = %.24f", c))
```

Output is:

```
b = 57.500000000000000000000000
c = 57.499999999999992894572642
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I want to print .999... or 1 in general case, but is there a way to print that value as .999...?

Answer (score 2):

In response to your edited question of how to print the number with greater precision, it's roughly the same as it is in C with `printf`.

```
> =string.format('%.17f', 0.1)
0.10000000000000001
```

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1811884/828255) as well.

As for the issues relating to floating point numbers, they've been covered numerous times in the past in other places. There's an informative link given in the comments that I'll copy [here](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Comment: great, with this I can close the question