# How can I change the Roblox (Lua) timer to display 3 decimals, and not more?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm currently writing a code in Roblox Studio (with the Lua language) and I'm making a timer, but the decimals randomly change from 3 to like 30. How can I fix this? Code:

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local Running = player:WaitForChild("Running")
--
local Text = script.Parent:WaitForChild("Time")
local Time = 0.00

while wait() do
    if Running.Value == true then
        Text.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(232,232,232)
        Text.Visible = true
        Text.Text = Time
        wait(0.125)
        Time = Time + 0.125
    else
        if Running.Value == false then
            Text.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255,47,92)
            Time = 0.00
        end
    end
end
```

I wanted the timer to update every 0.125 seconds, but instead it works a few times but then the decimals randomly switch up from 3 to 30. FOR EXAMPLE I wanted it to be 2.250 and not 2.25099999999999999999999999987. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

When you display the time, use the `string.format` function to format the number :

```lua
    Text.Text = string.format("%.3f", Time)
```

In this example, `%f` is used to display a floating point number, and `%.3f` limits the precision of that number to just 3 decimal points.

For more information, see this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1811889/2860267

Answer (score -1):

```js
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local Running = player:WaitForChild("Running")
--
local Text = script.Parent:WaitForChild("Time")
Text.Text="0.00"
Text.Visible=true
local tab={
    [true]=function()
        Text.TextColor3=Color3.fromRGB(232,232,232)
        while(wait(.125)and Running.Value)do
            Text.Text+=(.125)..[[
            ]]
            end
    end,
    [false]=function()
        Text.TextColor3=Color3.fromRGB(255,47,92)
        Text.Text='0.00'
    end
}
Running.Changed:Connect(function(v)
    tab[v]()
end)tab[Running.Value]()
```